# discord.py task.loop is not executed

Tags: loops, discord.py

i want to create a background task in discord.py executing every 5 seconds.

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def my_background_task():
        channel = await client.fetch_channel(BOT_CHANNEL_ID)
        print('true')
```

```
client.run(BOT_TOKEN)
asyncio.run(my_background_task())
```

I cannot figure out why the task is not running.What did i wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`client.run()` should always be the last line in your file, anything below it will not get executed until your bot shuts down.

This is also in the docs for `run()`.......
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=run#discord.Client.run

> This function must be the last function to call due to the fact that it is blocking. That means that registration of events or anything being called after this function call will not execute until it returns.

Tasks aren't supposed to be started using `asyncio.run()`, but using `.start` in an async context such as `setup_hook`.

The docs also show this pretty clearly (in this example using cogs, but starting is the same principle): https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html

Comment: Thank you, the problem is if im trying to start my function before client.run, i get a RunTime Error 'no running event loop'

Comment: My answer says you should call it in an async context like setup_hook, not at a random place in your file...